# HTTPs POST request using arm64 assembly

Tags: ssl, assembly, request, http-post, system-calls

I am programming on my phone for a challenge, my friend gave me. I am familiar with basics of assembly for arm64 devices and its syscalls.

My aim is to make a POST request to `discordapp.com`, but it uses https protocol, which means, I need a certificate or a library for ssl connection.
However, a part of my challenge is to not use any libraries and only plain assembly with syscalls.

I already managed to do some POST requests to http servers with pure assembly, but POSTing to `discordapp.com` says `Plain HTTP request sent to HTTPS port`.

Also, `discordapp.com` accepts self-signed certificates.

Now my question is actually: is there *any* way to make a POST request without ssl library on pure assembly?

My idea would be to capture outgoing request, sent with `curl` or `netcat` and to just send this over. Would this work?

Comment: Does discordapp.com reject POST requests made to its port-80 with plain HTTP?  As far as your question: is there *any* way?  Yes, of course there is.  Everything, including libopenssl, compiles to machine code, which you could copy or implement by hand.  Or implement just the equivalent parts you need.  "Is this thing another language can do possible in asm?" - the answer is always yes, the question is how much work it would be to write :P

Comment: *My idea would be to capture outgoing request, sent with curl or netcat and to just send this over. Would this work?* - No, the crypto used by SSL / TLS is intentionally designed to defend against replay attacks, so for example someone can't sniff your traffic and duplicate your online shopping orders to have 10000 laptops shipped to your house.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for replying  1) Yes, kinda, it says `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`; Well, of course I could do that, I will do it, if there are no possibilities left ;    2) Okey, thank you, I have never worked with this, so this was new information for me

Comment: To do this, you'd have to implement TLS which is quite involved.